# .NET Performance on AMD Processor

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, amd-processor

We are writing a data processing application in .NET 4 and recently tried to deploy our application to a AMD 6174 (12 core) processor. Historically we have used Intel and everything has been fine. The application is very parallel and we are getting multi-thread performance gains on Intel. However, on the AMD there really isn't a linear performance gain like one would expect. I am suspicious of a problem since the CPU utilization isn't maxed out. It smells like contention but I don't know where to look since this is a very platform specific issue. Ideas where to start?

Comment: We're going to need way more detail in order to even begin to guess at a reason for this.

Comment: So you optimized your code before for, what, a 4 or 8 core CPU.  Now you got 12 and you find out that you don't use them all?  That's normal.

Comment: No, I am changing the thread count of the app to match the core count of the CPU being used. All CPUs are used, but not peaking. Its a CPU bound app so I would expect linear scaling with addl cores.

Comment: I should also note that adding multiple threads results in an overflow slow down of other threads. EG, if with one thread the app runs at 100% then with two threads then the first thread runs at 70%.

Comment: Matt, Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it supports [OpenCL™](http://developer.amd.com/zones/OpenCLZone/Pages/default.aspx) so you might find the [AMD APP Profiler](http://developer.amd.com/tools/AMDAPPProfiler/Pages/default.aspx) interesting.

Comment: The technology is not exclusive to GPUs, but it takes advantage of them if available. It's about parallelism. Here is much better explained: [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

System performance depends on many components (CPU, L1, L2, L3 cache size, system bus speed, memory speed). In your case memory can be a bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

"However, on the AMD there really isn't a linear performance gain like one would expect." Based on what? I would assume that you have a series of benchmarks that you could run to measure the task completion time for a compute task correct? And since you have deployed on an intel box you should be able to set the thread cound to match the same number of processors (AMD -> intel) and if your numbers are about the same at least you can begin to formulate a testing plan for adding/testing the addition of more cores.